# Can not jump to Timer interrupt function in STM32F4 discoverty

Tags: timer, interrupts, stm32f4

I made a code to call Timer2 interrupt function like this :

```
timerx->TIMx_PSC    =42000;   // prescaler
timerx->TIMx_ARR    =2000;    // counting number
timerx->TIMx_CR1    |=0x90;   // auto reload, count down
timerx->TIMx_DIER   |=0x01;   // enable update interrupt
interruptsx->ISER[0]|= 1<<(TIMER2_INTERRUPT);   // enable timer_interrupt 
TIMER2_INTERRUPT=28   
timerx->TIMx_CR1    |=0x01;   // enable counter  
timerx->TIMx_EGR    =0x01;    // update generation
```

and

```
void TIM2_IRQHandler(){
if(timer2->TIMx_SR & 0x1){
gpio_toggle_off(gpio_A,GPIO_Pin_1);
number_display(gpio_D,number0);
}
timer2->TIMx_SR=0x0;
}
```

The problem is : it doesn't jump to TIM2_IRQHandler(). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Assuming you're using the CMSIS startup_stm32f4xx.c file, and assuming that the interrupt is actually firing (if it is, the execution point should be jumping to the default handler in the startup file), try including the (void) argument reference in the function declaration, i.e. _void TIM2_IRQHandler (void)_ instead of _void TIM2_IRQHandler ()_

Comment: I used startup_stm32f4xx.s and also try including (void) argument but it doesn't work. Do you have other suggestion??

Comment: The suggestion by markt is completely irrelevant. The compiler doesn't differentiate between having void or not in the argument list. A few ideas: have you enable the clock for the timer using the RCC peripheral? Is the timer actually counting? Try reading the `TIM2_CNT` register a few times in sequence; if they're all identical, it is most certainly stopped. Do any of the flags in TIM2_SR get set after a while?

Comment: I already enable the clock for timer using RCC.             After command : timerx->TIMx_CR1|= 0x01 ; TIMx->SR get set 1.                 After command : timerx->TIMx_R2 =0x01; After a while TIMx->SR get value 31, TIMx->CNT change its value. Then program stops at assembly command: STM r0!,{r1-r3,r6}. When I continue press F6 for debug, value TIMx-CNT changes.

Comment: @swineone Experience tells me that you're wrong.  You're right that the compiler doesn't care, but the preprocessor most certainly does.

Comment: @markt Congratulations on your knowledge of C trivia. Could you please elaborate on what kind of obfuscated yet reasonable (i.e. not constructed just to prove a point) preprocessor construction the OP would have to have used here so that your suggestion would have actually solved the problem?

Comment: do you have any ideas in my case ?

Comment: Are you configuring the interrupt in the NVIC?

Comment: Also, you may want to consider using the [STM32F4 Standard Peripherals Library](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF257901). Easier to read and program and less prone to errors. Also more portable and most examples seem to use it.

Comment: yes I configured Timer2 interrupt in the NVIC. I just start studying STM32F4 so I try control registers directly without using library.

Comment: I understand, but you may not get many people who know these processors to help since it is time consuming to look up and decrypt the numbers you use and since you have not included your full configuration. The standard peripheral library shows how to use these peripherals. For some reason they included the instructions in the source code (c files) instead of the header files so you should look there even though you would include the lib file and not the c files in your project. You really should get in the habit of using the library.

Comment: Have you turned the clock on for the timer?

Answer (score 2):

The following works (i.e. triggers interrupts) on my STM32F4Discovery board under the Coocox environment using GCC:

```
#include    "stm32f4xx.h"

int main (void) {
SystemInit();
NVIC->ISER[0] |= 0x10000000;
RCC->APB1ENR |= 1;
TIM2->CR1 = 0x0010;
TIM2->ARR = 0x8000;
TIM2->CR2 = 0;
TIM2->SMCR = 0;
TIM2->DIER = 0x0001;
TIM2->CR1 |= 0x0001;
while (1);
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler (void) {
TIM2->SR &= 0xfffe;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the reason is that I don't actually start the timer (set bit 0 of TIM2->CR1) until *after* everything else is configured.

Comment: Funny, because the only thing he does after setting bit 0 of TIM2->CR1 is setting bit 0 of TIM2->EGR, which as I understand manually generates an update event, so it doesn't seem like that would be a problem. Maybe if you could try running the exact same initialization procedure that he asked in the question (just don't remove the call to RCC that he didn't include), in the same order that he followed. I don't have any hardware with me now, otherwise I'd try. If it works for you this way it's clear the error is somewhere else, probably in his non-standard initialization code.

Comment: I checked my initialization code but can not find any problems. This is all my program https://github.com/ios198/ClockDigital

Comment: @ios198 Try replacing your code fragment with mine (without the SystemInit() call) and see if that fixes the problem (yes, the prescaler etc will be wrong, but try it anyway).  An outlier worth checking is maybe your use of 8-bit values is causing problems; try changing all the 8-bit values to 16-bit ones, and/or cast them explicitly as shorts, so e.g. TIM2->CR2 |= 0x90; becomes TIM2->CR2 |= (short)0x0090;  Yes I know it shouldn't matter but shouldn't isn't the same as doesn't.

Comment: Finally I can call timer TIM2_IRQHandler().The problem is from startup_stm32f4xx.s. I use this equation to calculate when an update event occur: Update Event(HZ)=Timer Clock/((TIM_PSC+1)*(TIM_ARR+1). In register RCC_CFGR(clock configuration register), I set Bit31:30=00 ( system clock selected =168MHZ), bit15:13=101( AHB clock divided by 4), bit7:4=0xxx (not divided). There for timer clock is 84MHZ.  For example if TIM_PSC=42000 and TIM_ARR=2, update event occur each 1ms. But update event doesn't occur as I want. Which problems I got here? Do I need to choose clock source first?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was to manually call `HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT()` after `MX_TIM2_Init()`. I'm using CubeMX and I thought it does that automatically, but it doesn't.